# Safely buy a used mobile

Tags: security

Is there any step I need to take after buying a used Android phone from a stranger?

Is restoring the device to defaults enough?

The hardware should be fine; I'm talking more about the OS itself and software issues (viruses and so on)

Comment: Completely wipe the phone and flash a stock ROM. That's as far as you need to go. Everything should then be back to the original state, right after you would have bought it in a store.

Comment: Yeah, but before buying the device, do search on web to be certain that tools exist, can be downloaded and would work on your device to wipe the slate clean and flash a ROM , otherwise you would have a device and nothing to do other than factory reset.